# How to provide condition for UPSERT in databricks - PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, upsert, delta-lake

I have a table `demo_table_one` in which I want to upsert the following values

```
data = [
    (11111 , 'CA', '2020-01-26'),
    (11111 , 'CA', '2020-02-26'),
    (88888 , 'CA', '2020-06-10'),
    (88888 , 'CA', '2020-05-10'),
    (88888 , 'WA', '2020-07-10'),
    (88888 , 'WA', '2020-07-15'),
    (55555 , 'WA', '2020-05-15'),
    (55555 , 'CA', '2020-03-15'),
    ]

columns = ['attom_id', 'state_code', 'sell_date']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

The logic is that for each attom_id & state_code we only want the latest sell_date
So the data in my table should be like

```
[
    (11111 , 'CA', '2020-02-26'),
    (88888 , 'CA', '2020-06-10'),
    (88888 , 'WA', '2020-07-15'),
    (55555 , 'CA', '2020-03-15')
]
```

and I have the following code to do it

```
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "demo_table_one") 

#perform the UPSERT
(deltaTable.alias('orginal_table')
    .merge(df.alias('update_table'), 
   "orginal_table.state_code = update_table.state_code and orginal_table.attom_id = update_table.attom_id")
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll("orginal_table.sell_date < update_table.sell_date")
    .execute())
```

But this inserts all the values in the table

Comment: whenNotMatchedInsertAll...

Comment: Missing one outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an SQL query first on the input to get the records with max value, appropriately, first.

Your  `.whenNotMatchedInsertAll()`  reveals that all records are not found and thus inserted.

I find the docs not so great on Databricks to be honest, but this is what I would do (you can do the SQL before as well):

```
data = [
    (11111 , 'CA', '2020-01-26'),
    (11111 , 'CA', '2020-02-26'),
    (88888 , 'CA', '2020-06-10'),
    (88888 , 'CA', '2020-05-10'),
    (88888 , 'WA', '2020-07-10'),
    (88888 , 'WA', '2020-07-15'),
    (55555 , 'WA', '2020-05-15'),
    (55555 , 'CA', '2020-03-15'),
    ]

columns = ['attom_id', 'state_code', 'sell_date']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("newer_data")
 
spark.sql(""" MERGE INTO DEMO_TABLE_ONE
              USING ( SELECT attom_id, state_code, max(sell_date) as sell_date from newer_data group by attom_id, state_code) AS NEWER
              ON DEMO_TABLE_ONE.attom_id = NEWER.attom_id AND DEMO_TABLE_ONE.state_code = NEWER.state_code
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                  UPDATE SET *
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                  INSERT *
          """)
```